# Pass parameters by POST from IONIC to PHP [CODEIGNITER]

Tags: angular, codeigniter, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello everyone I have created an app, with an API in PHP with CODEIGNITER but I can not read my body what it sends since it is seen in other cases than the sending of data by POST
is for example this way:

When I send it from JavaScript with HTML

```
user = "Ivan More Flowers"
```

But when I send it by IONIC it comes out this way

```
user: "Ivan More Flowers"
```

and this already returns me `null`

> My code in IONIC 3 :

```
//import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UsuarioProvider {

  api: string = 'http://localhost/xxxxxx/Welcome/'

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello UsuarioProvider Provider');
  }

  verificarUsuario(usuario: string, password: string) {

    let body = { usuario: usuario};

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });


    return this.http.post(this.api, JSON.stringify(body), {
      headers: headers,
      method: "POST"
    }).map(
      (res: Response) => { return res.json(); }
      );
  }

}
```

> And BACKEND, my code is:

```
function index() {
    $usuario = $this->input->post('usuario');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');        

    echo json_encode($usuario);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as shown below.Number of issues are on your method.

```
  api: string = 'http://localhost/xxxxxx/Welcome/'

  verificarUsuario(usuario: string, password: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    let body = { usuario: usuario};
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.api, body,options)
            .map((res: Response) => { return res.json();}).
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the answer, but now I get that the method is an 'OPTIONS' and I do not know what to do  :c, some is not installed for 'HTTP'

Comment: What happens that the data sends me this way looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr4VI.png